# How to create private channel in odoo?

Tags: email, odoo

I am trying to create ***private channel*** programmatically in ***Discuss*** Odoo12 but while creating it is giving me error that: `The requested operation cant be completed due to security restrictions.`

Then I tried like:

```
self.env['mail.channel'].sudo().create({})
```

Then it is creating private channel as a ***superuser***

But problem is that when I log in into my account I am unable to view that private channels because those were created by superuser.

How to display them or how to create private channel without **sudo()**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because there is a record rule that prevent user from creating channel that they are not member of it. So when you create it you need to include the partner of your user in channel members.

```py
self.env['mail.channel'].create({'name': 'Name of Channel', 
   'public': 'private', 
   'email_send': False, 
   # The user must join the group
   'channel_partner_ids': [(4, self.env.user.partner_id.id)]})
```

ir.rules are not applied on super user this why he can create a private group that he is not
one of its members.

Comment: but what to do if i want to add more than one partner_ids because there are two partners is private conversation

Comment: you can do `[(4,first_id), (4, second_id), ...etc]` or `[(6, False, [first_id, scond_id, third_id, ..etc)]` they are X2many commands. command 6 will replace any existing ids by the given list in write call, but in create there is no existing ids so it won't be a problem, 4 is used to add an id to X2many field.